# Azure devops copy bugs

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have area path for my app to write bugs in azure devops and when I create a new version I open a new area path for the specific version. I want to copy all the bugs I had to the new area path. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried one of the ways recommended in the docs? Like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/bulk-modify-work-items?view=azure-devops#edit-one-or-more-fields) and [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/bulk-modify-work-items?view=azure-devops#move-work-items-to-a-sprint)

Comment: Do you want to move your bugs to the new area or create duplicates and assign them to the new area?

Comment: I want to create duplicates in another area path, I can do it one by one by “create copy of work item” and change the area path in the copied work item.